# Download files using Python 3.4 from Google Patents

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, web-scraping

I would like to download (using Python 3.4) all (.zip) files on the Google Patent Bulk Download Page http://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto-patents-grants-text.html

(I am aware that this amounts to a large amount of data.) I would like to save all files for one year in directories *[year]*, so *1976* for all the (weekly) files in 1976. I would like to save them to the directory that my Python script is in.

I've tried using the `urllib.request` package, but I could get far enoughto get to the http text, not how to "click" on the file to download it.

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto-patents-grants-text.html'
savename = 'google_patent_urltext'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, savename )
```

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you seek for a command that will simulate leftclicking on file and automatically download it. If so, you can use Selenium.
something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
profile = FirefoxProfile ()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'D:\\') #choose folder to download to
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",'application/octet-stream')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto-patents-grants-text.html#2015')
filename = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"ipg150106.zip")]') #use loop to list all zip files
filename.click()
```

**UPDATED! 'application/octet-stream' zip-mime type should be used instead of "application/zip". Now it should work:)**

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a lot and is exactly what I needed. The only problem is that I now get a popup window asking me whether to open or save the file. Unfortunately the box with "Do this automatically for files like this from now on" is grayed out and I cannot click it. I tried including `profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)` or suppressing the alerts, but I couldn't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

The html you are downloading is the page of links. You need to parse the html to find all the download links. You could use a library like beautiful soup to do this.

However, the page is very regularly structured so you could use a regular expression to get all the download links:

```
import re

html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
links = re.findall('<a href="(.*)">', html)
```